# file.truncate() leaves white space in front of file python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, python-3.6

When I use truncate() it leaves white space at the front of the file. Which leads to me having gigabytes of white space that needs to be loaded into ram

```
f = open("test.txt","r+")
for i in range(0,100):
    f.truncate(0)
    f.write("End of file")
f.close()
```

Leaves a file that looks something like this

> ```
>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              End of file
> ```

How can I solve this?

Comment: what is your "test.txt"?

Comment: what are you trying to do with this code ?

Comment: @KarthikeyanKR test.txt is a test file, its just to show a point.

Comment: @Derlin This code is to show an example not to be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It behaves correctly when you use **f.seek(0)** in each iteration as follows:

```
    f = open("test.txt","r+")
    for i in range(0,100):  
        f.seek(0)
        f.truncate(0)
        f.write("End of file")
    f.close()
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for! Thank you!